# Can I change the script from one Matlab session while the other one is running that script?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have two Matlab sessions runs parallel.

To be handy, I just change the parameters that are hard-coded into the scripts for each run.

So my question is, can I change the script when the first Matlab session is running that script? After I changed and saved that very script, will the first Matlab session run according to the original version of the script?

I have multiple scripts that call each other. Will it be more complicated in this situation?

If the answer is YES, it will appear to me that for each run, Matlab will make a ad-hoc copy of all the scripts and run that copy regardless of the hard-disk changes.

Comment: @RobertP. you are partly correct. I actually tried it using a script with infinit for loop. However I then realized that I have multiple scripts calling each other so the point of my question actually goes to the second part, which is about the mechanism of matlab's parsing process. And this is answered in an awesome manner by Rody

Answer (score 9):

MATLAB's first step after you press "run" is to parse all the script/function's M-code and all of its dependencies into something akin to "byte code". That means that whatever MATLAB is running, is entirely in memory and thus not coupled anymore to what's in the M-file(s).

Therefore, you may indeed use another MATLAB session to change parameters in an M-file, save it, and run it in the new session, without affecting what the outcomes of the first session are.

Be sure to save or print the values of those variables though; working this way is a sure way to forget what values of those parameters belong to which session again :)

Note that this is NOT true for:

- data files, or other files explicitly read during runtime
- MEX files

Comment: Thanks. This answered the two aspects of my question.

Comment: +1, How do you know all that..? I mean, how matlab works with the computer memory and the dymanic access to files..?

Comment: @Adiel: Well, that's what "years of experience" tends to accomplish :) I've been in this man's position once...I spent maybe 30 hours (probably more) on figuring out how this works. I have felt the pain of losing my work because I didn't save the variables, had to re-do that work, discovered that changing data files *does* affect the outcomes, read all the documentation on it, etc. etc. etc. By now, I've had way more than [10.000 hours of practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliers_(book)) on MATLAB alone.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis hh..LOL. +1 on the comment also... :)

Comment: This is not the answer that matlab give. They say that each time a function call is made to a .m file, the version in the memory is updated. https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261376.

Comment: @ComptonScattering ...that's what Rune Allnor says, who is not affiliated with the Mathworks. However, hemmi7 confirms my story via some tests, while Steve Lord (mathworks employee) just advises not to try and make this work somehow, but instead use structured programming (neither confirms nor denies). I don't see how this contradicts my story...

Comment: @ComptonScattering plus, re-reading and/or re-parsing/re-compiling M-files on *each* function call would be unacceptibly slow...do you have reason to believe the above story is not true?

Comment: No I don't know about this. I just linked to an answer that gave a different story. I regret that my misunderstanding led me to imply erroneously that it was an official claim, but nonetheless, though you make a good argument, unless one of these two claims can be verified it is probably a relevant link for anyone looking for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

A better workflow would be to convert those scripts into modular functions that receive configurable parameters as input, as opposed to hardcoding the values in the code.

That way you call the same function in each MATLAB session without making any changes to the M-files, only each session passes different input arguments as needed.

---

To learn more about how MATLAB detects changes in M-files, run the following:

```
>> help changeNotification
>> help changeNotificationAdvanced
```

You also might also wanna read about the following functions: [`rehash`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html) and [`clear functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#inputarg_ItemType)

---

### EDIT:

One way to find out which scripts/functions are currently "loaded in memory" is to use [`inmem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inmem.html). Say for example we have the following script saved in a file available on the path (the same works for functions):

#### testScript.m

```
x = 10;
disp(x)
```

Now starting with a clean session, the script is initially not loaded. After calling the script, the file is loaded and remains in memory:

```
% initially not loaded
>> ismember('testScript', inmem())
ans =
     0

% execute script
>> testScript
   10

% file is cached in memory
>> ismember('testScript', inmem())
ans =
     1
```

Immediately continuing with the same session, make an edit to the file (for example change `x` to `99`). By checking the list of loaded functions/scripts again, you will see that MATLAB has already detected the change, and invalidated the cached version by removing it from memory:

```
>> % .. make changes to testScript.m file

% file is automatically unloaded
>> ismember('testScript', inmem())
ans =
     0

% execute the new script
>> testScript
    99

% the result is cached once more
>> ismember('testScript', inmem())
ans =
     1
```

I tested the above on my Windows machine, but I can't guarantee this behavior is cross-platform, you'll have to test it on Mac/Linux and see if works the same...

Comment: +1, couldn't agree more with your statement on workflow.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: thanks. I added a note showing how to check for loaded functions using `inmem` (this also works for scripts, classes, and MEX-functions).

Answer (score 0):

The script can definately be altered without influencing an ongoing run. However, if your flow gets more complicated it can be problematic to depend on what will happen:

Here are some flows you will not likely want:

- `main1` calls `sub`
- `sub` is edited
- `main2` calls sub
- `main1` continues to run and calls `sub` for a second time

In the above case I would expect the second run of `main1` to be calling the altered version of `sub`, but I would not depend on it.

- `main1` calls `sub`
- `sub` is edited
- `sub` called by `main1` hits a breakpoint

I am not even sure what will happen, but I believe that you will stop on the original line, but will see the edited code. So the line you find may not even be the line with the breakpoint anymore.

---

So to conclude: Don't alter your script frequently to change the output, rather give it inputs that will determine the output.